# The QR Code generated with the QR string via a JWT turns out to be invalid

Tags: twilio-api, authy

The problem is that I've gone through the API documentation of authy. Now there can be trust issues with the users to provide me their PII.

So I tried the Non-PII approach. For which I need a QR code to be scanned by my users.

Even though I've followed the exact process mentioned in the documentation after doing a test-drive of my application I tried scanning the QR code which gets generated in a php file that I've made. However the authy app after scanning the QR code says:

> Account couldn't be added. Please contact your service provider

P.S. I will provide the PHP code that I've made which generates the QR code. However I just want to know if this is a known issue about Not being able to add an account to my Twilio authy application.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same error. Have not been able to get a response from Authy dev support on what the error means (if it's a config issue, or issue with my code, etc). But, https://jwt.io/ says the token is correct, so I'm assuming it's an Authy config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have expiration date <= (issuing date + 15 minutes) on your JWT token. 
That was a reason I had an error 'Account couldn't be added. Please contact your service provider'.